# Reading file from src/test/resources

Tags: testing, classloader, junit5

I want to test a method, which should return lines from the file `src/test/resources` using `getClassLoader::getResourceAsStream()`. When I run the test I get NPE.

```
public class ResourceReader {

    public String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String lines;
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        try (BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        lines = sb.toString();

        return lines;
    }      
}
```

```
class ResourceReaderTest {
    private ResourceReader resourceReader;
    
    @Test
    void readFile_shouldReturnEveryLineSeparatedByNewLineFromFile() throws IOException {
        
        String actual = resourceReader.readFile("testCourses.txt");
        String expected = "Math, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "Physic, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "Biology, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "Chemistry, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "Geometry, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "Philosophie, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "English, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "German, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "Informatik, Solving of exircises" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + "Geography, Solving of exircises";
        
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
        
    }
}
```

Project explorer looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxd1V.png)

Build Path properties for Project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e742Y.png)

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxWa1.png)

I already tried to set BuildPath and I think in the properties it seems to be OK. But I am not sure.
Do you have any ideas, what could be wrong here?